# Making droppables only accept certain draggables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I feel like this could possibly be a concept a little complicated to explain out of context with the actual website I'm doing, so I'll explain why I want to do this, which should help you understand what I'm after.

Basically I'm making a kids nutritional website. The page in question requires the kids to look at a little food groups image, and recreate it using draggables and droppables on the next page.

[image: website screengrab]

Each of the food images on the right are draggable, and each colour on the left has an invisible droppable div on top. The idea is that after the user has dragged each piece of food on to the correct colour, **then** a splash screen would appear to show that they're correct. But this would only happen if **each** food draggable is in the right droppable.

I am fairly inexperienced with `javascript` and `jQuery`, and I have no idea where to begin. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Welcome, Poopy Balls!" - Brilliant

Comment: (1) *"I am fairly inexperienced with jQuery"* -- You do not really need jQuery to do this. Javscript is simple enough. (2) *"I have no idea where to begin"* -- You can begin from here -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/nyczybgh/2/

Comment: I didn't even realise the poopy balls was there, I hadn't changed the name in a while haha.

 Thanks for that fiddle @Abhitalks . The reason I only brought up jQuery was that I like that things can be dropped anywhere, which feels a lot more satisfying and responsive than the native javascript stuff. Otherwise that fiddle is helpful, but doesn't address having multiple items in the one drop-zone. 

Like I intend for there to be four of those images that needs to be dropped in the green rather than just the one, you know?

Comment: @SamBarnett: The fiddle was not intended to provide you with a ready-made code which serves all of your requirements. You asked where to begin and that fiddle just gives that - a push in the direction. Use that fiddle to expand, tweak whatever to fit your use-case. Hint: Use data attribute to control that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out a way to do it using the `accept` option, and implementing a counter to determine when the correct colour was full. See working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1a9jjear/).

The only issue I have with this method is it won't let you make any decision other than the correct one, so you could mindlessly go for trial and error to complete it. But since my application will be dealing with children, that perhaps isn't so important.

Answer (score 1):

Here a working example - keep in mind this script may not covering all of your requirements but might help you developing what you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/xu4qoexq/3/

The correct order for testing is: drag1 = drop1, drag2 = drop2 and so on.

In the drop event we need to attach some information from the draggable item to the droppable area:

```
$(this).data('item', ui.draggable.data('item'));
```

Use some data attributes on draggable items and droppable areas and compare them like in the function below:

```
function compareItems() {
    var result = 'correct';
    $('.drop').each(function (i, e) {
        if ($(this).data('item') !== $(this).data('drop')) {
            result = 'wrong';
        }
    });
    alert(result);
    return false;
}
```